# Acces to Principal outside the 'router-outlet' in main component in JHipster Angular

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am changing the JHipster layout in a generated application.

I can inject the `Principal` in any component rendered inside the `router-outlet`, however, if i try to inject it in the main component, an error is shown whenever i try to login/logout (if i refresh the page everything shows fine).

The code causing the problem is

```
export class JhiMainComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private jhiLanguageHelper: JhiLanguageHelper, private router: Router, principal: Principal) {}
```

If i remove the `principal: Principal` everything works again, if i add this injection then the login stops working with the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined
>       at LoginService.logout (webpack-internal:///./src/main/webapp/app/core/login/login.service.ts:33)
>       at NavbarComponent.logout (webpack-internal:///./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:49)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///ConsuldentAppModule/NavbarComponent.ngfactory.js:695)
>       at handleEvent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:19661)
>       at callWithDebugContext (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20755)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20458)
>       at dispatchEvent (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:17110)
>       at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:17557)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js:1044)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420)

I need the property because i have some conditional styles which are selected depending if the user is loged in or not (here im trying with the method isAuthenticated())

```
<div id="page-container" class="page-container fade page-sidebar-fixed page-header-fixed show" [ngClass]="{
    'page-without-sidebar': isPageWithoutSidebar() || !isAuthenticated()
  }">
    <router-outlet name="header" *ngIf="!pageSettings.pageEmpty"></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name="sidebar" *ngIf="!isPageWithoutSidebar() && !pageSettings.pageEmpty && isAuthenticated()"></router-outlet>

    <div id="content" class="content" [ngClass]="{
    'content-full-width': pageSettings.pageContentFullWidth,
    'content-inverse-mode': pageSettings.pageContentInverseMode,
    'p-0 m-0': pageSettings.pageEmpty
  }">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <jhi-footer *ngIf="pageSettings.pageWithFooter"></jhi-footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what i did was to create a service with the variables

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PageSettingsService {
    pageSettings = pageSettings;

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

Then i inject this service in the main component, where i use the `pageSettings` property

```
export class AppComponent extends JhiMainComponent implements OnInit {

    pageSettings;
    // window scroll
    pageHasScroll;

    ngOnInit() {
        super.ngOnInit();
        // page settings
        this.pageSettings = this.pageSettingsService.pageSettings;
    }
}
```

Then i edited the login service (this part does not feel clean, but works)

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoginService {
    constructor(private principal: Principal, private authServerProvider: AuthServerProvider, private pageSettingsService: PageSettingsService) {}

    login(credentials, callback?) {
        const cb = callback || function() {};

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.authServerProvider.login(credentials).subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.principal.identity(true).then(account => {
                        resolve(data);
                        this.pageSettingsService.pageSettings.pageWithoutSidebar = false; //Added
                    });
                    return cb();
                },
                err => {
                    this.logout();
                    reject(err);
                    return cb(err);
                }
            );
        });
    }
...
    logout() {
        this.pageSettingsService.pageSettings.pageWithoutSidebar = true; //Added
        this.authServerProvider.logout().subscribe();
        this.principal.authenticate(null);
    }
}
```